# 10DOF IMU GY-80 Navigation with ROS Running on Intel Edison

Tags: navigation, ros, intel-edison, inertial-navigation

I have a 10 DOF IMU GY-80 and ROS Kinetic running on Intel Edison. Using IMU only I want a marker to navigate, in Gazebo, on predefined floor layout plan when the person with IMU and Intel Edison start walking. What is the easiest approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you Can Navigate With Only an IMU. In order To Do Navigation The robot First needs to know where it is and where It want to go.

if order to do That u need some sort of Localization(SLAM Or Visual Odometry Or GPS for Outdoor environments) and if Where the robot needs to requires a visual detection You will also need at least a Camera and Computer Vision.

you can always do blind navigation and publish velocities you need statically and in gazebo it might work (no noise) but in real world I doubt you can get it to work correctly